# I would like to add a column conditional on other columns

Tags: r, if-statement, transform

I would like to add a column named "order" based on the other columns named Onion, Garlic, and Olive.

If any of the three columns is 1 for each row, then I would make a new column that says "Yes". If a row only contains zeros, then I would like to write "No".

Being specific,
Below would be the original data, and

| ID | Onion | Garlic | Olive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I would like to add the fifth column "Order" which says "Yes" if any of the columns 2,3,4 says 1 and otherwise "No".

| ID | Onion | Garlic | Olive | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Yes |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Yes |

I wanted to use the transform function, but I got confused about how to add multiple if statements within the transform function.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(Order = case_when(if_any(Onion:Olive, ~ .x == 1) ~ "Yes", TRUE ~ "No"))
```

---

Or with `transform`

```
df1 <- transform(df1, Order = ifelse(rowSums(df1[-1] == 1) > 0, "Yes", "No"))
```